# mysql returning a subset of a query is slower than returning the superset of a query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, subset

Suppose I do

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM xyz e
            JOIN abc cs ON e.rss = 'text' AND e.rdd = cs.xid
            JOIN def c ON cs.cid = c.xid
            JOIN jkl s ON c.sid = s.nid
          WHERE s.flag = 0;
```

This would reveal:

```
1, 'SIMPLE', 's', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,Index_8', 'x1', '1', 'const', 1586, 'Using index; Using temporary'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'c', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,sid', 'x2', '4', 's.nid', 40, 'Using index'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'cs', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,cid', 'x3', '4', 'c.nid', 1, 'Using index'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'e', 'ref', 'rss,rdd', 'x4', '141', 'const,cs.nid', 12, 'Using where; Using index; Distinct'
```

However, suppose I do

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM xyz e
            JOIN abc cs ON e.rss = 'text' AND e.rdd = cs.xid
            JOIN def c ON cs.cid = c.xid
            JOIN jkl s ON c.sid = s.nid
          WHERE s.flag = 0 AND c.range_field <= 10;
```

This would reveal

```
1, 'SIMPLE', 'c', 'ALL', 'PRIMARY,school_nid,Index_5', '', '', '', 56074, 'Using where; Using temporary'
1, 'SIMPLE', 's', 'eq_ref', 'PRIMARY,Index_8', 'PRIMARY', '4', 'c.school_nid', 1, 'Using where'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'cs', 'ref', 'PRIMARY,cid', 'x3', '4', 'c.nid', 1, 'Using index'
1, 'SIMPLE', 'e', 'ref', 'rss,rdd', 'x4', '141', 'const,cs.nid', 12, 'Using where; Using index; Distinct'
```

ie. while the first query is only scannding 1586 rows, this one is scanning over 56074 rows

This is despite the fact that the second query is supposed to return a SUBSET of the first query's results.

Ie. out of the 1586 results of the first query, return those who have c.range_field <= 10.

Is there a way to modify this query so that the number of rows scanned will be <=1586 since the result of this second query is just a subset of the result of the first query

Comment: Have you tried using the first query as a subquery to select from? I other words, `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * ...) x WHERE x.range_field <= 10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the 2nd query is a subset of the 1st one does not matter from the performance perspective.

In the first query, there's no filter involved for the c table, while in the 2nd one there's one on `c.range_field`.
As you can see in the 1st explain plan (`Using index`), the first query can compute the resultset ONLY using the index, which is a fast operation (from the index, mysql can deduce the location of the wanted rows and only read these ones which explains the lower amount of scans). In the 2nd explain plan, MYSQL has to compute the resultset using common database hd blocks which is a slow operation (full table scan: the rows are read one by one and evaluated that way).

The solution for you is to evaluate the possibility of including the `c.range_field` column to one of the `possible keys` indices commented in the `c` column of the 2nd explain plan.

Comment: yea Index_5 index in the second explain contains the c.range_field (it's the only column in that index)...is this query doomed to be performing that many row scans then?

Comment: @pillarOfLight, it might be possible that mysql evaluates that the subset of `c.range_field <= 10` is not representative enough to be using the index, and chooses to proceed a FTS instead. Sometimes indices are counter productive if the affected columns are not selective enough.

Comment: @Sebas set it better than I was going to, so I'll just tag it on here: It _is_ using a different driving table, because of your added condition. It chooses `def` in the second query, where it had used `jkl` in the first.

Comment: @pillarOfLight to investigate so, run this query: `select count(*)/count(distinct range_field) from def`. if the result is above 20, this would likely validate my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

As you are filtering by `c.range_field` and `def c` is the third table in your `FROM` clause, the filtering happens on the result set of joining set of the three tables as there are no indexes. I would suggest you go by Sebas' answer and create an index on `c.range_field`.

An alternative to this, which I would use myself, is to set `def` as the driving table. This means, start your `FROM` clause with `def` table, preferably followed by `jkl`. This would filter the rows on the first and second tables before joining them with the third and the fourth.